# Ionic 3 - How to use a cordova plugin repo?

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Im trying to use this plugin in my Ionic3 app:

> https://github.com/VirtuoWorks/CanvasCameraPlugin

I have managed to install the plugin with:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/VirtuoWorks/CanvasCameraPlugin.git && cordova prepare
```

My problem is what to do next, i need to include the plugin into the app, with ionic native plugins this can be done like this:

```
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
```

But what should i use for the CanvasCamera plugin?

```
import { CanvasCamera } from '??????';
```

My current code:

```
declare let CanvasCamera: any;
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform) {
    this.canvasCameraStart();
  }

  canvasCameraStart() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      var options = {
        quality: 75,
        destinationType: CanvasCamera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        encodingType: CanvasCamera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        width: 640,
        height: 480
    };
      CanvasCamera.start(options);// here call the plugin's method
    });
 }

}
```

Comment: did you get solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare plugin's object as shown below.

```
declare let CanvasCamera: any;

@Component({
  ...
})
export class TestPage {

  ...

  myPluginMethod() {
     this.platform.ready().then(() => {
       CanvasCamera.start(options);// here call the plugin's method
     });
  }
}
```

**Update:** You need to do as shown below.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform) {

 this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.canvasCameraStart();
   });

 }

  canvasCameraStart() {
     let options = {
        quality: 75,
        destinationType: CanvasCamera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        encodingType: CanvasCamera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        width: 640,
        height: 480
    };
      CanvasCamera.start(options);// here call the plugin's method
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Where do i add the declare line? If i add it on the line below the "imports" i get a TS error "[ts] ',' expected".

Comment: OK just do this and let me know:  `declare let CanvasCamera: any;`

Comment: That worked fine :) I updated to the code you supplied and now i get a runtime error "Runtime Error
Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: CanvasCamera is not defined ReferenceError: CanvasCamera is not defined at http://localhost:8123/build/main.js:66:34 at t.invoke "

Comment: Can you show your latest `code`? Put that on your question area.

Comment: Please see the **Update**

Answer (score 0):

Contributors for this module made a type definition file for this module as stated in [Angular 2 support #8](https://github.com/VirtuoWorks/CanvasCameraPlugin/issues/8).

You can install the type definition file following the instructions on npm [@types/cordova-plugin-canvascamera](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/cordova-plugin-canvascamera).

You should then be able to use CanvasCamera in your ts files according to [Typescript 2.0. “types” field in tsconfig.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826848/typescript-2-0-types-field-in-tsconfig-json/39827904#39827904)

Best Regards.