# Angular 6 application cannot find namespace 'google'

Tags: angular, typescript, namespaces, tsconfig

This question has appeared similarly in many places where the solution is to simply add

```
import { } from '@types/googlemaps';
```

which worked as a solution in past versions of angular. The issue appeared now that I am using Angular 6+

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'google'.
TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'google'.
```

There are numerous errors like this anywhere I use google maps types. For example:

```
let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
```

I can quickfix the issue by inserting `// @ts-ignore` above all lines that use google maps, but I am much more interested in a true fix. But the fact this works makes me feel it's a tsconfig issue which I am not super confident about.

I can confirm that googlemaps is installed inside node_modules/@types, but I am not sure about the tsconfig

**ts.config**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

I created a [Stackblitz Example](https://angular-google-maps-demo-oezprn.stackblitz.io) which throws a Reference Error if you view the console. I don't know what to try next.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

So I came across the problem earlier on GitHub and this worked for me:

- `npm install --save-dev @types/googlemaps`
- Adding to all my `tsconfig*.json`: `types: [ "googlemaps"]`
- Adding at the top of my file: `declare const google: any`;
- Adding at the end of the body of my `index.html`:

  `<script async defer type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=****"> </script>`

Try it out and tell me whether it works.

Comment: I was only ever looking at my tsconfig.json, by adding "googlemaps" to my tsconfig.app.json and suddenly it's happy. Can't believe I couldn't find this anywhere! Cheers

Answer (score 10):

The tsconfig.json file that really needs to be updated is in src/tsconfig.app.json.

That files overrides the types property of compilerOptions of the tsconfig.json file in the root directory with an empty array so you must add the types definition for googlemaps there.

For example:

```js
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["googlemaps"]
  },
  "exclude": ["test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Comment: In general in order angular compiler (not typescript compiler) can find your types you need to specify types in src/tsconfig.app.json as stated above. In addition you need to specify type sub folder name in  node_modules/@types folder. E.g. for chart.js it will be 'chart.js'. Just explore the folder node_modules/@types

Answer (score 8):

Adding it to the types array of my tsconfig compiler options has never worked. But if you have the @types/googlemaps installed, you can reference this at the top of your .ts file using:

`/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />`

cf. [Triple Slash Directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html)

Comment: This was the only answer, that worked for me (using Angular 8 with cli)

Answer (score 7):

I fixed it by installing  **@types/google-maps** not  *@types/googlemaps*

just run this

```
npm install @types/google-maps --save
```

and import google in your component using

```
import { google } from "google-maps";
```

Answer (score 4):

I've found something, if you are using AGM you can fix it importing:

```
import {} from '@agm/core/services/google-maps-types';
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently I came across this issue and it occurs due to many reasons I mention all the possible solution here:

**Solution 1:**

i) If you haven't enabled your google Places API to go through this link [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=en-EN#enable_apis) to enable it.

ii) install @types/googlemaps in your project using `npm i @types/googlemaps --save-dev` for more details click [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/googlemaps)

iii) Add `"types": ["googlemaps"]` this to your tsconfig.json most of the case file name is tsconfig.app.json if you are curious about types check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826848/typescript-2-0-types-field-in-tsconfig-json) on StackOverflow.

iv) restart your server

In most cases, there is no need for declaring any google variable and the above solution works in my case also.

**Solution 2:**

if solution 1 does not work include this `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>` in your index.html and put your api key in this link.

in one of my project solution 2 works.

**Solution 3:**

and if solution 1 and solution 2 do not work write this code in your ts file `declare const google: any;`

I hope this will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using AGM running into this error:

```
Cannot find name 'google'.
```

Running this worked for me:

```
npm install @types/google-maps --save
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using AGM and if well this problem exist was the product of other problem. That is here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/48574   And the solution was:
"I found a temporary solution, install an earlier version of @types/googlemaps in the package.json, I added @types/googlemaps: "3.39.12" to my devDependencies, now the production build works !" If you will be try this , first run: npm uninstall @types/google-maps