# How do I import a Javascript library into Typescript when the package has a declaration file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to use the type definitions in the [callbag](https://github.com/callbag/callbag) library. This library declares its type definition file in its package.json. It is not uploaded to DefinitelyTyped. When I try to import the library, I get the error:

```
Cannot find module 'callbag'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?
```

This is how I import it:

```
import type { Sink } from 'callbag';
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

I also tried adding `"types": ["callbag"]` to the tsconfig.json, but it didn't work.

How do I get typescript to recognize the types for this library?

Comment: At first, your import statement looks correct. Could you paste in your `tsconfig.json` into your question (using edit)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript 2.0. "types" field in tsconfig.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826848/typescript-2-0-types-field-in-tsconfig-json)

Comment: I have added the tsconfig.json. The linked answer does not work for me. I tried it with types in my tsconfig.json.

Comment: @Eva can you please try setting "moduleResolution": "node" in tsconfig.json, as evident in error.

Comment: That worked, but can you explain why? AFAICT the module was es6. Why does it also need to be set to node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in the comments, I needed to add `"moduleResolution": "node"` to my tsconfig.json. Not sure why because nothing that I'm working on is related to Node.js. But that's what worked.