# Property '$vuetify' does not exist on type - when using Nuxt.js with Vuetify

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have this error for a particular part in the code when accessing `this.$vuetify` in my Nuxt.js app.

```
 ERROR  ERROR in components/equipment/QuickInfoCard.vue:21:20                                                                                                                   19:51:29
TS2339: Property '$vuetify' does not exist on type '{ width(): string; height(): "100%" | "9em"; }'.
    19 |     },
    20 |     height() {
  > 21 |       switch (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name) {
       |                    ^^^^^^^^
    22 |         case 'sm': return "9em"
    23 |         default: return "100%"
    24 |       }
```

I already tried to add the TS type since that was a suggested solution

```js
// tsconfig.json
"compilerOptions: [
    ...
    "types": [
      "@nuxtjs/vuetify", // <<
      "@types/underscore",
      "@types/node",
      "@nuxt/types",
      "@nuxtjs/auth-next"
    ]
    ...
]
```

Comment: The documentation also says to add `@nuxt/vue-app`; not sure if that will make a difference

Comment: sadly does not help

Answer (score 0):

Please, verify if you have the '@nuxtjs/vuetify' inside of the buildModules in your nuxt config.

Next, try access to vuetify from the global $nuxt, for example:
this.$nuxt.vuetify

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You may have opened your editor in the wrong directory, causing files like your package.json and tsconfig.json to not be found. If using VSCode, the "code ." command needs to be opening the exact project directory, or else this error can occur. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

enter code hereA better solution that i have found is just adding a *"vuetify"* in the tsconfig.ts file under *"types": [...]*

Note : i'm using typescript in my implementation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it in your `tsconfig.json` by:

- including `"node_modules/@nuxtjs"` in your `"typeRoots": [...]`
- including `"vuetify"` in your `"types": [...]`.

The reason why is that `typeRoots` contains all the directories TypeScript looks for to get its type definitions, and `types` is the name of the library TypeScript looks for individually.

References:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots
- [Typescript 2.0. "types" field in tsconfig.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826848/typescript-2-0-types-field-in-tsconfig-json)

Comment: Let me know if this works for anybody.